# convert multiple .pcd files into one PCD file

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

whenever I try to convert .bag file using the following command:

rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd input_file.bag topic output_directory

to pcd file, I am getting multiple pcd files.

How can I obtain single pcd file from a bag file, using point_cloud_assembler. Or I should use laser_cloud_assembler?

I think my .bag file contains point clouds, so that I should extract data in order to create .pcd file. After I want to use this pcd file to convert it into stl file in cloudcompare in order to use it gazebo world

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327296/convert-multiple-.pcd-files-into-one-pcd-file/) by [Nurbek](https://answers.ros.org/users/40848/nurbek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathur](https://answers.ros.org/users/53240/mathur/) on 2020-04-07**:
have you solved this. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use laser_cloud_assembler. I think [link text](http://www.theconstructsim.com/merge-laser-scans-single-pointcloud/) and [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans) this will help you. After doing this hopefully you will get one PCD Data then you can use cloudcompare to convert into stl file and you can import that stl file in the gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) with karma: 139 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nurbek](https://answers.ros.org/users/40848/nurbek/) on 2019-07-03**:
yes, they helped a lot, thanks!